# drawRect not called when using auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, drawrect

I'm converting a view from shocks and struts to autolayout but now the custom drawing code that is in drawRect is not being called.  Is this expected behavior and if so how can I work around this?

Comment: Can you see what are the values of origin & size of `frame` in `initWithFrame:` or `initWithCoder:`?

Comment: origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=0, height=1440).

Why would the width be 0?

Comment: Were you checking if it was called by adding a breakpoint in `drawRect:`?

Comment: Yeah I put one on initWithFrame to get the coordinates, then had another one on drawRect.  Does it matter that it's a UIView on a UIScrollView?

Answer (score 6):

In your view's init (our in the class where you instantiate your view) set the ContentMode:

```
yourView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
```